# Result two joins SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I attended an interview yesterday where they asked a question to join a table `demo1` which has values A, B, C, D with another table Demo2 which has values C, D. I want result C,D using Join.

How do we do that? I tried but was not able to find a solution.

```
Create table Demo1(ID char(1))
Insert into Demo1
select 'A'
Insert into Demo1
select 'B'
Insert into Demo1
select 'C'
Insert into Demo1
select 'D'

Create table Demo2(ID char(1))
Insert into Demo2
select 'A'
Insert into Demo2
select 'B'
```

Comment: Your `Demo2` table has A & B but the question says it should have C & D, which is correct?  Also what did you try to to get the result?  It'd be a lot better to show your attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once simple approach is via a LEFT JOIN

```
Select D1.*
 From  Demo1 D1
 Left  Join Demo2 D2 on D1.ID=D2.ID
 Where D2.ID is null
```

**Returns**

```
ID
C
D
```

Comment: @user3442289 Leaning is a process.  Just keep at it and I would suggest watching SO.  I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 1):

Inner Join returns the records which exist in both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM Demo1 INNER JOIN Demo2 ON Demo1.ID = Demo2.ID 
Result:
C
D
```

Outter Join returns all records from Demo1 with those that exist in Demo 2.

```
SELECT D1.ID as D1, D2.ID as D2 FROM Demo1 D1 FULL OUTER JOIN  Demo2 D2 ON D1.ID = D2.ID  
Result:
A, NULL
B, NULL
C, C
D, D
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the common values use

```
SELECT * FROM Demo1 INNER JOIN Demo2 ON Demo1.ID = Demo2.ID
```

and if you want values from A which are absent from B use

```
SELECT * FROM Demo1 FULL OUTER JOIN Demo2 ON Demo1.ID = Demo2.ID WHERE demo2.ID IS NULL
```